# error installing ruby 1.9.3 on linux server

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

Hey I'm just to update ruby on a linux server I ssh into. I know there a lot of threads on this but most are for installing on mac osx (which i dont have an issue with). This is the error log thats outputted:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p551..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: unknown/libc-2.12/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more 
information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for unknown.
Install:
press any key to continue
Install: build-essential libreadline zlib1g libyaml libc6 libgdbm ncurses
press any key to continue
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/swampu6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p551 to /home/swampu6/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551....
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /home/swampu6/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /home/swampu6/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/CVE-2015-1855-p484.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #configuring.............................................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #post-configuration..
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #compiling...
Error running '__rvm_make -j48',
showing last 15 lines of /home/swampu6/.rvm/log/1437856022_ruby-1.9.3-p551/make.log
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.1.9
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling dmyencoding.c
compiling version.c
compiling miniprelude.c
compiling array.c
compiling bignum.c
make: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable
make: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable
compiling dmyversion.c
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

this is the content of the make.log per a commenter's request:

```
[2015-07-25 16:27:22] __rvm_make
__rvm_make ()
{
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /home/swampu6/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551
PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/home/swampu6/perl5/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/home/swampu6/.rvm/bin:/home/swampu6/bin:/home/swampu6/.rvm/bin
command(2): __rvm_make -j48
++ make -j48
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -shared
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.1.9
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling dmyencoding.c
compiling version.c
compiling miniprelude.c
compiling array.c
compiling bignum.c
make: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable
make: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable
compiling dmyversion.c
++ return 2
```

Comment: what version of rvm are you running?

Comment: i'm running rvm 1.26.11

Comment: The error message "vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable" suggests that your machine is running out of resources during compilation. It might be that your machine is not powerful enough to compile Ruby, but that seems unlikely. Can you upload the rest of /home/swampu6/.rvm/log/1437856022_ruby-1.9.3-p551/make.log somewhere (i.e. a gist) so we can view it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that, since RVM is trying to compile ruby with the command `__rvm_make -j48` (which tells the compiler to try to parallelize the compilation across 48 different jobs), your host system is running out of space to do so. Before I get to a possible solution, here are some high-level thoughts:

1. Production systems generally shouldn't be compiling their own Ruby versions. Instead, ship the compiled binaries to the node (e.g., as a Debian package) and don't even install RVM.
2. `rvm` does a lot of magic to try and hide the details of what its doing from the end-user, but in my experience that's more trouble than it's worth. Use [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and build Ruby only when you need to.

Anyway, for your current issue, I think your best bet is to try to override the `-j` flag to a smaller value. There are a few methods, but first try this:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 -j 1                # from http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
```

If that doesn't help, double-check that the `-j` argument in `__rvm_make -j 48` actually changed to 1 in the log. If it did, try a smaller number. If it didn't, then try this:

```
MAKEFLAGS=-j1 rvm install ruby-1.9.3  # from https://twitter.com/avdi/status/130720270733410305
```

Hopefully one of those works!